# How to fix error TS2339: Property 'tz' does not exist on type 'Moment'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, datetime, momentjs, moment-timezone

In rails app, I created frontend app which uses `angular`. Here I am using `moment` and `moment-timezone` like

```
"moment": "^2.22.2",
"moment-timezone": "^0.5.23",
```

In `timezone.service.ts` importing and using like

```
import * as moment from 'moment-timezone';
import {Moment} from 'moment';

public parseDatetime(datetime:string, format?:string):Moment {
    var d = moment.utc(datetime, format);

    if (this.ConfigurationService.isTimezoneSet()) {
      d.local();
      d.tz(this.ConfigurationService.timezone());
    }

    return d;
  }
```

While running `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` getting
ERROR in src/app/components/datetime/timezone.service.ts(55,9):

> error TS2339: Property 'tz' does not exist on type 'Moment'.
> src/app/components/datetime/timezone.service.ts(80,23): error TS2339:
> Property 'tz' does not exist on type 'typeof moment'.

`npm` version is `6.4.1`

`node` version is `v8.12.0`

`ruby` verson is `ruby 2.6.1p33 (2019-01-30 revision 66950) [x86_64-linux]`

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to update your version of moment-timezone.  There is a documented bug on 5.28, but since you're using a lower version in might exist there as well.

https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/906

this states that 5.33 and 5.31 are without error and in a rails app, using `moment-timezone 5.40` I am able to us the `tz` function without error.

```
ds.tz("America/Chicago")
```

From my working package.json

```
"moment": "^2.29.4",
"moment-timezone": "^0.5.40",
```